# maximize a JFrame in a multi monitor setup

Tags: java, swing, jframe, maximize, multiple-monitors

My Swing application uses JFrames. When one of the JFrames is dragged to a second monitor and the maximize button is pressed, it maximizes itself to the size of the (smaller) primary monitor. Can that behavior be fixed?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your operating system settings.  Being able to maximize a JFrame to multiple different monitors is a standard ability.

Comment: I have just tried this and it works fine. I think @jzd is right: something is wrong in your environment.

Comment: Chances are it is the videodriver somehow. Thanks for verifying. I'll run some tests.

Comment: ATI video driver updated. Created a test JFrame (completely vanilla) but with no change. Swapped primary and secondary monitor; the JFrame always maximizes correctly on the primary monitor. Tested using Java 1.7.0_01 and 1.6.0_14.